# how to make dynamic loops in php?

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I am working on one project where i have to input one array and it will produce one array as an output in following format.

**Input >>**

```
<?php

 $option = array(
     0 => array(
         "name" => "material",
         "value" =>
             array(
                 0 => "cotton",
                 1 => "polister",
                 2 => "khadi"
             )
     ),
    1 => array(
        "name" => "color",
        "value" =>
            array(
                0 => "Red",
                1 => "Blue"
            )
    )

 );
```

**Output >>**

```
<?php

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [material] => cotton
            [color] => Red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [material] => cotton
            [color] => Blue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [material] => polister
            [color] => Red
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [material] => polister
            [color] => Blue
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [material] => khadi
            [color] => Red
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [material] => khadi
            [color] => Blue
        )

)
```

i have did this work done by following code but it will only work for (3 <= count($option))

```
<?php

 $option = array(
     0 => array(
         "name" => "material",
         "value" =>
             array(
                 0 => "cotton",
                 1 => "polister",
                 2 => "khadi"
             )
     ),
    1 => array(
        "name" => "color",
        "value" =>
            array(
                0 => "Red",
                1 => "Blue"
            )
    )

 );
 $combination = 1;
 $i_count = count($option);

 for ($i = 0 ;$i < $i_count ; $i++){
     $j_count[] = count($option[$i]['value']);
     $combination = $combination * count($option[$i]['value']);
 }
 $final_arr = array();
 for($i=0;$i<$combination;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<$i_count;$j++){
        $key = $option[$j]['name'];
        $final_arr[$i][$key] = "";
    }
}
$f = 0;
if($i_count >= 1) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($option[0]['value']); $i++) {
        if ($i_count >= 2) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($option[1]['value']);$j++) {
                if($i_count >= 3){
                    for ($k = 0; $k < count($option[2]['value']);$k++) {
//                        echo $option[0]['value'][$i]."\n".
                             $option[1]['value'][$j]."\n".
                             $option[2]['value'][$k]."\n <br><br><br>";

                        $key = array();
                        for($m=0;$m<$i_count;$m++){
                            $key[$m] = $option[$m]['name'];
                        }

                        $final_arr[$f][$key[0]] = $option[0]['value'][$i];
                        $final_arr[$f][$key[1]] = $option[1]['value'][$j];
                        $final_arr[$f][$key[2]] = $option[2]['value'][$k];
                        $f++;
                    }
                }
                else{
//                        echo $option[0]['value'][$i]."\n".
                            $option[1]['value'][$j]." <br><br><br>";

                        $key = array();
                        for($m=0;$m<$i_count;$m++){
                            $key[$m] = $option[$m]['name'];
                        }

                        $final_arr[$f][$key[0]] = $option[0]['value'][$i];
                        $final_arr[$f][$key[1]] = $option[1]['value'][$j];
                        $f++;

                }

            }
        }
        else{
            for ($k = 0; $k < count($option[0]['value']);$k++) {
//                echo $option[0]['value'][$k]."<br><br><br>";

                $key = array();
                for($m=0;$m<$i_count;$m++){
                    $key[$m] = $option[$m]['name'];
                }

                $final_arr[$f][$key[0]] = $option[0]['value'][$k];
                $f++;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
// $key = "color";
// $final_arr[0][$key] = "";
 echo"<pre>";
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
echo "combination count :".$combination."<br>";
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
print_r($option);
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
print_r($final_arr);
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
 echo"</pre>";
?>
```

but i want to work with unlimited amount of input array-size

means if input is like this

```
$option[0] = array(...);
$option[1] = array(...);
$option[2] = array(...);
$option[3] = array(...);
$option[4] = array(...);
$option[5] = array(...);
```

then also it will produce output

Comment: is option array count is fixed for only 2 array?

Comment: Give more information for option array, count(option) > 2? if yes what would be his structure?

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy no sir it will work for count(option) in (1,2,3) means 1 to 3

Comment: @SiderTopalov while count(option) > 3 then result array structure is based on total combinations of all those option[$n]

Comment: kindly one more input array and your desired output for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

If you write nested for-loop in your code, the layer of loop will be fixed.
That is, your layer of for-loop will not be dynamic.

To make it dynamic, we can put loop in a function and determine how many times we call it on runtime.

We can divide and conqure this problem.

a) A solution to input array $option is all combination of first option and a solution to input array $option without first option.

solution($option) = fisrt option X solution($option - first option)

b) If there is only 1 element in array $option, simply build an array of the key-value [name] => [value] to all value and return the array.

By implementing this method, i wrote following code:

```
<?php

$option = [];
$option[0] = [
    'name' => 'material',
    'value' => [
        'cotton',
        'polister',
        'khadi',
    ],
];

$option[1] = [
    'name' => 'color',
    'value' => [
        'Red',
        'Blue',
    ],
];

$option[2] = [
    'name' => 'Attribute3',
    'value' => [
        'A',
        'B',
    ],
];

$option[3] = [
    'name' => 'Attribute4',
    'value' => [
        'X',
        'Y',
    ],
];

$combination = buildCombination($option);

print_r($combination);

function buildCombination(array $option): array {
    if (empty($option)) {
        // combination of an empty array is empty array
        return[];
    }

    // take first option away from $option and put it in $firstOption
    $firstOption = array_shift($option);

    $result = [];
    $name = $firstOption['name'];
    $valueCollection = $firstOption['value'];

    // b)
    if (empty($option)) {
        foreach ($valueCollection as $singleValue) {
            $result[] = [$name => $singleValue];
        }

        return $result;
    }

    // a)
    // $subCombination = solution($option - first option)
    $subCombination = buildCombination($option);
    foreach ($valueCollection as $singleValue) {
        foreach ($subCombination as $subCombinationEntry) {
            $newEntry = [$name => $singleValue];
            $newEntry = array_merge($newEntry, $subCombinationEntry);
            $result[] = $newEntry;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [material] => cotton
            [color] => Red
            [Attribute3] => A
            [Attribute4] => X
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [material] => cotton
            [color] => Red
            [Attribute3] => A
            [Attribute4] => Y
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [material] => cotton
            [color] => Red
            [Attribute3] => B
            [Attribute4] => X
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [material] => cotton
            [color] => Red
            [Attribute3] => B
            [Attribute4] => Y
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [material] => cotton
            [color] => Blue
            [Attribute3] => A
            [Attribute4] => X
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [material] => cotton
            [color] => Blue
            [Attribute3] => A
            [Attribute4] => Y
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [material] => cotton
            [color] => Blue
            [Attribute3] => B
            [Attribute4] => X
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [material] => cotton
            [color] => Blue
            [Attribute3] => B
            [Attribute4] => Y
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [material] => polister
            [color] => Red
            [Attribute3] => A
            [Attribute4] => X
        )

     ...
)
```

Hope this is helpful for you.